# How to run Linq Query on ListView in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to run a Linq Query onto a ListView in C#.

My aim is to check-up list of all younger students except the oldest in each group of my ListView

```
BindingList<StudentsList> MyStudents = new BindingList<StudentsList>();

private void Query()
{   
var results = MyStudents.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.DateTime)
                            .Select(x => x.First())
                            .ToList();}         

public class StudentsList
{
public StudentsList()
        public string Student { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string Interest { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Linq works on a collection. List View is a control class not a collection, it has a property probably named Data or ItemSource which is a collection. The same way you filled the list view. The same way you can retrieve the data. Once retrieved you can apply linq on it. Please elaborate for more info on what you want to do.

Comment: Please show the code that includes your `ListView` list. The code here only has `BindingList`.